# trim all 'spaces' from String

Tags: java, regex, parsing

I am parsing a PDF and getting a lot of Strings with `\t, \r, \n,\s`... And they **appear on both ends of the String and don't appear in order**. So I can have 
ex:
 "`\t\s\t\n`Some important data I need surrounded by useless data `\r\t\s\s\r\t\t`"
 
. Is there any efficient ways to trim these Strings?
What I have so far which isn't good enough because I want some symbols.:

```
public static String trimToLetters(String sourceString) {
        int beginIndex = 0;
        int endIndex = sourceString.length() - 1;
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[A-Z_a-z\\;\\.\\(\\)\\*\\?\\:\\\"\\']");
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(sourceString);
        if (matcher.find()) {
            if (matcher.start() >= 0) {
                beginIndex = matcher.start();
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(sourceString);
                String sourceReverse = sb.reverse().toString();
                matcher = p.matcher(sourceReverse);
                if (matcher.find()) {
                    endIndex = sourceString.length() - matcher.start();
                }
            }
        }
        return sourceString.substring(beginIndex, endIndex);
    }
```

Comment: You would do worse than to invoke `stringInstance.replaceAll("[[:space:]]", "")`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `trim` method of the `String` should be able to remove all whitespace from both ends of the string:

> `trim`: Returns a copy of the string, with leading and trailing whitespace omitted.

P.S. `\s` is not a valid escape sequence in Java.

Comment: Thats the first thing I tried. Or maybe the pdfs contains letters that can't be rendered to .txt file.

Comment: @wtsang02 what is the issue that you are facing with 'trim' method?

Comment: @Jayamohan String.trim() didn't work for me in JSP. Or maybe its some other error causing. Let me try again with just trim().

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Thanks. The problem was in jsp page. Now I can use trim() to trim it.